# Smoothness of sections of some multiple of a smooth ample divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $\geq2$ and $H$ be an ample divisor such that $|H|\neq\emptyset$. If the general sections of $H$ are smooth, what about $nH$ for $n\geq1$?

I know for $n\gg1$ this is right by Bertini's theorem and Matsusaka's theorem since in this case it is very ample, but I don't know in general.

Although $\Gamma(X,H)\subset\Gamma(X,nH)$, we can not use the sections in $\Gamma(X,H)$ to construct those in $\Gamma(X,nH)$ because by Nakai-Morshizon theorem the components with intersect to each other.

If you want you can let $X$ is a Fano variety of dimension $\geq3$.

---

Thank you for your any help!!!

Comment: If $P=H$ is a non Weierstrass point on a curve of genus $>2$, then $\#|H|=\#|2H|=1$. In that case the non-zero sections of ${\cal O}(H)$ are smooth (and have divisor $P$) and the non-zero sections of ${\cal O}(2H)$ are all non smooth (and have  divisor $2P$).

Comment: @DamianRössler Thank you!